# Assigning column names in a txt file in python

Tags: python, multiple-columns

I have the following code that extracts needed data from a xml file. I can save it to terminal, and open it with no problem. I am in trouble inserting column names to the txt file, however. I have been searching the answer but found no right solution. Would anyone help me here? Thank you!!

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = f

for program in root.findall('program'):

    programID = program.find('programID')
    season = program.find('season')
    print programID, season


sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to write data to a file in Python is to call `.write(content)` on the file object, not to redirect stdout to it.

Instead of all your lines messing with `sys.stdout`, try this:

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")  # Open the file in (w)rite mode

f.write("programID,Season\n")  # Header line 
for program in root.findall("program"):
    programID = program.find("programID").text
    season = program.find("season").text
    line = programID + "," + season + "\n"
    f.write(line)

f.close()  # Outside the loop
```

There are better ways to make the string for `line`, but we don't need to worry about those at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, but I received this error message when I ran the code Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nyp.py", line 102, in <module>
    line = programID + "," + season + "\n"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Element' and 'str'  I am completely new to python and I highly appreciate your patience.

Comment: @Hsun-YiHsieh I didn't realise that `programID` and `season` weren't already strings, sorry.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: str(programID), str(season) generates objects. Instead, programID = program.findall('program').text    season = program.find('season').text generates the text context. But Adam's solution is right. However, I still cannot insert column names - programID and season, with this set of code. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Aha, thanks for teaching me.  I'll update the answer for any future questioners.  :D

Comment: You helped a lot. I did not know such a simple solution. But could you help with adding column names? :D

Comment: Edited my answer again (added a header line); is that what you were after?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you!! This is awesome!! :)