# Failed to query in sqlite by using column names

Tags: python, sqlite

This is an extended question from [Assigning column names in a txt file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165636/assigning-column-names-in-a-txt-file-in-python/38165919#38165919)

I have the following code. I extracted data from a xml file and saved it into a txt file. Then I imported it in sqlite3. Here, I can see the whole database. However, while I query, I can only use programID. For the rest, I all failed. I am not sure where I did wrong. I appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

```
try:
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

root = ET.parse("complete.xml")

f = open("conductor.txt", "w") # Open the file in (w)rite mode

f.write("programID, season, workID, composerLastName, composerFirstName, workTitle, OpusNumber, conductorLastName, conductorFirstName\n")
for program in root.findall('program'):
    programID = program.find('programID').text
    season = program.find('season').text
    worksInfo = program.find('worksInfo')
    if worksInfo is None:
        work = ''
    else:
        work = worksInfo.find('work')
        if work is None:
            workID = ''
            composerName = ''
            workTitle = ''
            conductorName = ''
        else:
            workID = work.get('ID')
            composerName = work.find('composerName')
            if composerName is None:
                composerName = ''
            else:
                composerName = composerName.text
                composerLastName = composerName.split(',')[0]
                if len(composerName.split(',')) > 1:
                    composerFirstName = composerName.split(',')[1]
                else:
                    composerFirstName = ''
            workTitle = work.find('workTitle')
            if workTitle is None:
                workTitle = ''
            else:
                workTitle = workTitle.text
                WorkTitle = workTitle.split(',')[0]
                if len(workTitle.split(',')) > 1:
                    OpusNumber = workTitle.split(',')[1]
                    conductorName = work.find('conductorName')
                    if conductorName is None:
                        conductorName = ''
                    else:
                        conductorName = conductorName.text
                        conductorLastName = conductorName.split(',')[0]
                        if len(conductorName.split(',')) > 1:
                            conductorFirstName = conductorName.split(',')[1]
                        line = programID + "," + season + "," + workID + "," + composerLastName + ',' + composerFirstName + ',' + WorkTitle + "," + OpusNumber + ',' + conductorLastName + ',' + conductorFirstName + "\n"
                        f.write(line)

f.close()
```

Comment: sqlite> .separator ","  sqlite>.import conductor.txt conductor sqlite> select * from conductor returns the whole dataset, sqlite> select programID from conductor works, but sqlite> select season and all others fail.

Comment: What is the error that gets reported when you execute `select season from conductor` on SQLite shell?

Comment: Thank you. Here is the error Error: no such column: season

Comment: You need to check your `conductor` table to see the column names. Use the `pragma table_info(conductor)` command to check the table scheme.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. This command returns '0,programID,TEXT,0,,0
1," season",TEXT,0,,0
2," workID",TEXT,0,,0
3," composerLastName",TEXT,0,,0
4," composerFirstName",TEXT,0,,0
5," workTitle",TEXT,0,,0
6," OpusNumber",TEXT,0,,0
7," conductorLastName",TEXT,0,,0
8," conductorFirstName",TEXT,0,,0'  It looks like I have " season" instead of season...Indeed, if I use " season", it works...But I am confused where those "" come from?

Comment: you use the "," as separator, if you look at your conductor.txt file, the first line is `programID, season, workID`, so the leading space is taken as part of the column names. To fix the issue, remove the spaces from this line in your code `f.write("programID, season, workID, composerLastName, composerFirstName, workTitle, OpusNumber, conductorLastName, conductorFirstName\n")`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zhliu03 indicated, the cause of the problem is the leading space is taken as part of the column names.

This solves the problem:

```
f.write("programID,season,workID,composerLastName,composerFirstName,workTitle,OpusNumber,conductorLastName,conductorFirstName\n")
```